# From Discrete choice to Conjoint utilities

Tags: r, marketing, conjoint-analysis, choice-modeling, clogit

I'm having trouble figuring out how to correctly calculate conjoint part-worth-utility from a discrete choice experiment.

I have recently run a pilot study to analyse in R where I used the packages “support.CEs” and “survival” and I’m trying to figure out how to calculate conjoint part-worth-utilities from the coefficients, but not sure I’m doing it correctly.

For simplicity sake I will use a simplified example about rice to explain my problem.

The experiment contains the following attributes and levels.

```
Region = c("RegA", "RegB", "RegC"),
Cultivation = c("Conv", "NoChem", "Organic"),
Price = c("1700", "2000", "2300")),
```

I then used the `clogit()` function to analyse the results of the experiment using the following model:

```
RES ~ ASC + RegB + RegC + NoChem + Organic + Price + strata(STR)
```

This gave the following result:

```
        coef    exp(coef)   se(coef)     z   p
ASC     4,443   85,035      0,483    9,199   0,00E+00
RegB    0,469   1,599       0,137    3,417   6,30E-04
RegC    0,968   2,632       0,108    8,996   0,00E+00
NoChem  0,752   2,120       0,177    4,257   2,10E-05
Organic 1,165   3,205       0,141    8,252   1,10E-16
Price  -0,002   0,998       0,000   -9,732   0,00E+00
```

Now my assumption is that the part-worth-utilities for each attribute level is simply the corresponding coefficients, with the remaining level not part of the model (`RegA` for the Region attribute) being 0?

However, while looking at another R package called `conjoint`, devised to analyse rating based conjoint, I noticed that they determined the last levels value in a different way:

```
 # Example 1
 library(conjoint)
 data(herbata)
 ul<-caUtilities(hpref,hprof,hlevn)
 print(ul)
```

To find the remaining levels utility they take the sum of all other levels in the attribute and subtract it from 0, meaning `RegA` would have an utility of -1,437 instead of 0.

0 - (0,469 + 0,968) = -1,437

I can't quite figure out the logic behind this as it seems to considerably widen the distance in utility between `RegA` and `RegB/RegC` while keeping the distance between `RegA` and `RegC` fixed.

At first I dismissed this as being a mistake, however I then saw that the example for the `ChoiceModelR` package also calculated the remaining attribute levels as the inverse sum of the rest.

**Is this truly the correct way to determine the utility of the remaining attribute level?**

Secondary question:

If so, how is the result of say the “marginal willingness to pay” function mwtp() reliable, when it would sets `RegA` as 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the R package "conjoint" does. The part-worth utilities (PWU) are the model estimates. The PWU for the reference categories will depend on the coding scheme you used to describe the variables. If standard **dummy coding** (0/1), then the PWU of the reference category is 0. An alternative, that has been (a little bit) used in the DCE literature, would be **effects coding** (-1/0/1). In this last case, the PWU for the reference category is: **(sum of estimates for the remaining categories) x -1**.

In your case: PWU_RegA = (0,469 + 0,968) * -1 = -1,437.

**Important**: The difference between dummy and effect coding does not technically matter (Try the 2 coding schemes and you will see that in both cases the model log-likelihood will be the same - well, it should!). There is a paper criticizing the use of effects coding (http://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/104911/).